# Convert Mysql Query to Elastic Search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

in regards to my earlier question [ElasticSearch Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771999/mysql-query-to-elasticsearch) where mapping and doc sample is given
 I want to convert this MySql query to Elasticsearch. Here is the mysql query

```
Select * from us_data where phone!=0 AND city_code IN ('Homestead','Hialeah','Key Biscayne','Miami Beach','Miami','North Miami Beach','Ochopee','Opa Locka') AND state_code='FL' AND (name like '%appliance%' or city_code like '%appliance%' or address like '%appliance%' or phone like '%appliance%')
```

Looking forward for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query should help you. Note that in your mapping you have `contact_no` while in the above query you've mentioned `phone`.

Nevertheless, I've made use of `contact_no` so that it sticks with the mapping.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "city_code.keyword": [
              "Homestead",
              "Hialeah",
              "Key Biscayne",
              "Miami Beach",
              "Miami",
              "North Miami Beach",
              "Ochopee",
              "Opa Locka"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "state_code.keyword": "FL"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "*appliance*",
            "fields": ["name","city_code","address","contact_no"]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "contact_no.keyword": "0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've used variations of [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html), [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and [Multi-Match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query.

Note that I've used Term Query/Terms Query on the `keyword` fields as from the sql-query it appears you want an exact match, while I've used `multi-match` on the `text` fields.

Let me know if this helps!